# Conversion of .shp to EPSG:4326 has slight offset

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

I just started this project where I need to project the Dutch municipalities on a map. Luckily this seems very easy with the help of `GeoJSON`. However, I'm having a slight issue where my conversion to `EPSG:4326` seems slightly off and I don't know why or how to correct it (The original .shp-file is in the Dutch Rijksdriehoekscoördinaten system).

My steps:

I downloaded the most recent shapes from cbs.nl: http://download.cbs.nl/regionale-kaarten/shape-2015-versie-1-0.zip

I used OSGeo4W to transform the Gem_2015.shp file to GeoJSON with the option `-t_srs EPSG:4326` to convert to lat/lon:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON gem.geojson Gem_2015.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326`

This results in a nice geojson file. But if we take a closer look at one entry, it seems that it has a slight offset: 
https://gist.github.com/Waterstraal/95f73c22662775e7169d079f222869cb/60ae6e504efcd929bfebf8ae23fdb173038a7604

Am I using a wrong projection, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shapefile's .prj file does not contain the datum shift parameters from Amersfoort to WGS84, because the ESRI world handles datum shifts differently from the GDAL world.

GDAL tries to make a guess about the EPSG code, but sometimes fails. So you have to add explicitely that you have EPSG:28992 data:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON gem_rd.geojson Gem_2015.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -s_srs EPSG:28992
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here (which is to use the correct srs): http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=163623#p163623

The correct srs (which i saved at rd.srs):

`+title=Amersfoort/Amersfoort +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.999908 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812`

The new command that now results in a valid geojson:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON gem_rd.geojson Gem_2015.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -s_srs rd.srs`

The result: https://gist.github.com/Waterstraal/95f73c22662775e7169d079f222869cb/925d4b73094e7bc5a449949316d80774df603a1d

Could someone still explain me why the correct srs is not provided in the dataset? The set *does* come with a `gem_2015.prj` file, which seems to contain somewhat of the same data:

`PROJCS["RD_New",GEOGCS["GCS_Amersfoort",DATUM["D_Amersfoort",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",155000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",463000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",5.38763888888889],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999079],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",52.15616055555555],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Comment: The WKT is an Esri one, and it could be that the ogr2ogr converter doesn't understand some of the information like "Double_Stereographic" or "GCS_Amersfoort".

Comment: Such errors are often due to slightly different +towgs84 parameters. Check for example this link http://epsg.io/28992.proj4. You can check from the file \OSGeo4W\share\proj\epsg which parameters your OSGeo4W has for EPSG:28992 (if it is your coordinate system).